# Permanently disable touchpad in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I want to permanently disable the touchpad, because it is nearly impossible to use the computer with the touchpad active. The Ubuntu settings lets me do this, however every time I reboot the machine or the screen is locked, the touchpad is enabled again and frequently causes horrible accidents (typing passwords in the wrong window etc).

Things I have tried that do not work:

1. Turning it off in `/etc/rc.local` (it is turned off, but then something turns it on again)
2. Turning it off in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` (again, it is turned off, but re-enabled)

I have considered doing some physical damage to the device, but it seems like there should be a software solution.

(I'm aware of suggested dupes, but they do not address the question of how to PERMANENTLY disable the touchpad, there are many ways to do it for a while until the system decides it knows better and re-enables it)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove your touchpad drivers, remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` via

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

this command removes also `xserver-xorg-input-all`, but that's only a meta package.

> Description-en: X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage  This
>   package depends on the full suite of input drivers for the X.Org X
>   server  (Xorg).  It does not provide any drivers itself, **and may be
>   removed if you wish to only have certain drivers installed**.

Comment: I love it short and precise - so therefore : +1 =)

Comment: @cl-netbox Only therefore? That's the perfect answer =)

Comment: Did you know that there sometimes are several ways to reach a goal ? =)

Comment: @cl-netbox Sometimes? Always! =)

Comment: You are absolutely right - so thanks for confirming that my answer is AWESOME ! =)

Comment: @cl-netbox You're welcome :)

Comment: Than use the gray tick at the left side of my answer and click. Means, the answer is valid. ;)

Comment: Just wanted to test a bit more. The only thing that is not disabled is that it is still possible to press the touchpad for a mouse click. However this is acceptable since it requires some force.

Comment: That's not a thing of synaptics :\ Maybe we could disable your "mouse".

Comment: and to fix touchpad always disabled,  install all those things :D

Answer (score 2):

I added a disable and enable shortcut to my keyboard.

```
# xinput
```

Resulted in

[image: xinput]

In system settings>keyboard>shortcuts I added enable and disable touchpad shortcuts.
[image: shortcuts]

[image: Add Shortcut]

The two commands for my computer are:

```
xinput --enable 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
```

and

```
xinput --disable 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
```

Yours may have a different device name.

Finally I assigned the two commands to "Menu" and "Shift+Menu" because I never use the menu key normally.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Yes, this works, but the problem was to find a way to make it happen automatically. By the time I notice the touchpad is on, something annoying has usually already happened.

Comment: @JohanRönnblom you can add the command into your ~/.bashrc file and it will automatically executed when you login next time

Answer (score 1):

To disable the touchpad permanently install dconf-editor by opening a terminal and executing :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open **dconf-editor** and go to -> **org** -> **gnome**-> **settings-daemon** -> **peripherals** -> **touchpad**.

Uncheck **touchpad-enabled**.

If the touchpad nevertheless will be re-enabled after reboot - open a terminal and execute :

```
xinput list
```

Search for the touchpad device ID and execute :

```
xinput set-prop * "Device Enabled" 0
```

Note : * = touchpad device ID

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

**Alternative** (a helpful contribution from **Jacob Vlijm** - see his comment below) :

Open a terminal and execute :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

Adding

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false"
```

to Startup Applications will also permanently disable the touchpad.

Comment: My answer is a lot easier than yours :P =)

Comment: (removed comment, this may work permanently if done exactly as outlined, but the other solution is simpler and cleaner imo)

Comment: @JohanRönnblom : If using the other solution you will have to reinstall touchpad drivers in case you need them again.

Comment: I have tried this solution too now and it does not work permanently. Whenever the machine is rebooted or the screen is locked, the touchpad gets reenabled again. The other solution does almost exactly what I want.

Comment: @JohanRönnblom : most important is that you are satisfied and we could help you, so it is absolutely okay to go with the other one - enjoy ubuntu experience !